# How to add a multi-color flush logo to a flat surface?

Tags: fusion360

I've been banging my head against the desk for two days so it's time to ask for help. This is the second thing I've ever tried to design in Fusion 360, so very much a newbie.

I'm trying to make some coasters for my dad for Christmas. What I've done.

1. Created a sketch
2. Created a square
3. Added some fillets
4. Extruded
5. Right-clicked on the top surface and created a sketch
6. Imported SVG of logo and positioned it
7. Extruded the stuff on the logo that should be white by -0.4 mm into a new body
8. Extruded the stuff on the logo that should be red by -0.4 mm into a new body

This is what it looks like in F360.
[image]

I now export to STL and open in OrcaSlicer. First problem I notice is that not all the bodies that were created are paintable. For example, I can pain "NEW YO" but the "R" and "K" just don't show up. Second problem is that this is what my first three layers look like (sliced at 0.20 mm). I'm assuming my error is on the F360 side but I just don't understand what it is. I've watched several videos on YT about doing this, but they usually are doing a single color and are either embossing or debossing it. I want it flat.

[image: Layer 40]
[image: Layer 39]
[image: Layer 38]

After that it goes to infill and the rest looks fine.

Comment: Welcome Graig. I suggest using a question for a title. For example, 'How to add a multi-color flush logo to a flat surface?' or anything that describes your main question better.

Comment: I always print upside down in such cases, you can print the colors first, an then the rest of the coaster or casing, see [e.g. this card box](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:6310774). If you look closely to the STL of the logo, you see them stitched with a very thin layer to connect all the parts. Reading your question I don't quite grasp the problem. If it is either STL generating of slicer related problems. How do the stl's look in an STL viewer? Please add images.

Comment: Try extruding the to-be-colored parts 0.01mm above the surface too. This smells to me like Z-fighting, two different surfaces at same height, floating point error (essentially randomness) decides which will be on top.

Answer (score 2):

Do two extrusions in F360.

The first will be a 'cut' into the coaster. This removes the volume from the the coaster that will be your lettering and graphics from your stencil.

The second will use the same profile and depth. Except this time it will be a 'new body.' This will fill the volume that was removed in the first operation.

Looking at 'Bodies' in your F360 expandable tree in the upper left corner, your coaster should be one. Every letter and graphic that is isolated and not touching another letter or graphic should be another body after the last extrusion.

If you have a dual extrusion printer the coaster can be one extruder. All other objects can be the other extruder.